# running tests locally (before committing) with cloudbees

Tags: jenkins, clojure, cloudbees, compojure

I've created a compojure web-app with cloudbees - awesome set up so far. I'm just wondering how to run tests locally before I push them up to jenkins to kick off the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out: lein test

(i'll leave this since cloudbees uses SO as their blog).

Comment: Yes I use lein test heavily - very handy. It would be possible to amend the plugin to run tests before pushing, if that is what people wanted.

Comment: that sounds useful, @Michael. Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: I maintain the lein plugin - https://github.com/michaelneale/lein-cloudbees/blob/master/src/leiningen/cloudbees.clj - so somewhere there we could hook in test - but need to have it optional somehow. Feel free to fork and play.

Comment: can lein ask the user - ie if the test fails - we could ask them if they still want to deploy? not clear on the aims here.

Comment: Ah - you want to run a check before pushing to *git*. Does that mean that Jenkins does the actual deploying of your app? if so - probably is another lein plugin to help with that - if not - probably a good idea to create one (and they are easy !)

Comment: yes, that's right, @Michael. I want a plugin that runs the tests as part of the git push (and the push would fail if the tests fail). ...Maybe. I'm not sure. Let me have a think about that. It seems I could just alias "push" on my machine to run "lein test" and then "git push" based on the results.

Comment: or you can create your own lein plugin that is "lein push" to do that ! lots of options.